# SQL remove from running total

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem that I don't know how to fix .. here is the code and wanting result

```
if object_id('tempdb..#A') IS NOT NULL drop table #A
create table #A (ID int, Value decimal(6,2), value2 decimal(6,2), Result decimal(6,2))

insert into #A (ID, Value, value2, Result)
values
(1, 10, 25, null),
(1, 10, 25, null),
(1, 10, 25, null),
(2, 10, 5, null),
(2, 10, 5, null),

select * from #A
```

So, I would like to take Value away from "value2", if there are left overs, **just update it to 0**, for **next row i would take those "left overs"** and use them to take away from, with next Value

I would like to get results like this...

```
ID  Value     value2    Result
 1    10        25        0
 ----------------------------
 1    10        25        0
 ----------------------------
 1    10        25        5
 ----------------------------
 2    10        5         5
 ----------------------------
 2    10        5         10
```

So as you can see with ID 1 ... it would be:

```
10 - 25 = 0
10 - 15 = 0
10 - 5  = 5
```

I hope you understand what I am trying to do here ... let me know if I can explain more ...

Comment: SQL tables are inherently unordered.  There is no "next value", unless you have a column that specifies the ordering.  Also, you should tag your questions with the database you are using.

Comment: you'll need to implement this via some script which can *hold* the last left over...SQL has no such feature IMO....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help of Gordon and using some part of his idea ... i did something, that at this moment seems to work, but will need a lot of more testing

```
if object_id('tempdb..#testDataWithRunningTotal') IS NOT NULL drop table #testDataWithRunningTotal
select id, value, value2, cast(null as float) as Result 
   into #testDataWithRunningTotal
from #A order by id;

declare @runningTotal float = 0, @previousParentId int = null;

update #testDataWithRunningTotal
set
   @runningTotal = Result = case when @previousParentId <> id 
                                then value2 - value                                     
                            else 
                                case when ISNULL(@runningTotal,0) < 0 then value * (-1)
                                     when value2 - value < 0 and ISNULL(@runningTotal,0) = 0 then value2 
                                     when value2 - value > 0 and ISNULL(@runningTotal,0) = 0 then value2 - value                                
                                else
                                     case when @runningTotal - value < 0 and ISNULL(@runningTotal,0) = 0 then value 
                                          else @runningTotal - value
                                     end
                                end
                            end,
   @previousParentId = id
from #testDataWithRunningTotal 

update tst
set Result = case when Result > 0 
            then 0 
            else Result * -1 
         end
from #testDataWithRunningTotal tst

select * from #testDataWithRunningTotal
```

So, I am keeping @runningTotal running with update, and allowing it to go under 0 ... once it goes less then 0 it means that is moment where SUM of value is greater then SUM of Value2 ... so i keep the record there, and at end of this calculation i do update.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want the cumulative sum of the difference, with no negative values allowed.  Most databases support window functions, which include cumulative sums:

I am going to assume that `id` really specifies the ordering.  You need some column that serves this purpose because SQL tables represent *unordered* sets and have no ordering.

But, something like this should work:

```
select a.*,
       sum(case when value2 >= value then 0 else value - value2 end) over
           (order by id) as result     -- or whatever the column is that specifies the ordering
from #A a;
```

Comment: I used your idea and modified it a bit with other stuff i came up with, so i got to final solution, thank you!