# Want to create view with dynamic values

Tags: sql, view

I have table like

```
rno  intial  consumed  bal
1    500     120       380
2    0       100       -100
3    0       80        -80
```

I  am getting values as above but I need values like below 
I have intial set value 500 from that I want to deduct consumed value and should show balance as prvious balance like 380 should show in intial balance for next row please help me as I was stucked here while creating view for this but I have suceeded creating procedure for this but I need only view

```
rno  intial  consumed  bal
1    500     120       380
2    380     100       280
3    280      80       200
```

Comment: Seems to me you need running total .... check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34354688/sql-remove-from-running-total or google SQL running total

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention which RDBMS, but this seems to give you the running total you're looking for in a view for SQL Server (and possibly other RDBMSs)

```
SELECT * INTO Test FROM (VALUES
(1, 500, 120),
(2, 0, 100),
(3, 0, 80)) A(rno,initial,consumed);


GO    
CREATE VIEW SomeView AS    
WITH A AS(
  SELECT rno
    ,initial
    ,consumed
    ,SUM(initial - consumed) OVER (ORDER BY rno ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) bal
  FROM Test)
SELECT 
    rno
    ,COALESCE(LAG(bal) OVER (ORDER BY rno), initial) initial
    ,consumed
    ,bal
FROM A;
GO

SELECT * FROM SomeView ORDER BY rno

rno         initial     consumed    bal
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           500         120         380
2           380         100         280
3           280         80          200
```

Comment: oh thanks a lot i am trying implement this in my query i am very happy with this thanks a lot i think you are great expert..i will thank full to you a lot